# operational error with Digital ocean and django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Getting this error after using DO's one-click install for Django and uploading all my stuff. I set up my settings and urls files. Not really sure what the issue is, I've never seen it before.

The error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/login/
SSL error: unknown protocol
expected authentication request from server, but received S
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _legacy_get_response
            response = self._get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
            return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in _wrapper
            return bound_func(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py in bound_func
                return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/allauth/account/views.py in dispatch
        return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/allauth/account/views.py in dispatch
                                            **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/allauth/account/views.py in get
            request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py in get
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data()) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/django/django_project/allauth/account/views.py in get_context_data
        site = get_current_site(self.request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/shortcuts.py in get_current_site
        return Site.objects.get_current(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py in get_current
            return self._get_site_by_id(site_id) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py in _get_site_by_id
            site = self.get(pk=site_id) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in manager_method
                return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get
        num = len(clone) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __len__
        self._fetch_all() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _fetch_all
            self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self)) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in __iter__
        results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
            cursor = self.connection.cursor() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in cursor
        return self._cursor() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in _cursor
        self.ensure_connection() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in ensure_connection
                self.connect() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py in __exit__
                six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in ensure_connection
                self.connect() ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py in get_new_connection
        connection = Database.connect(**conn_params) ...
▶ Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async) ...
▶ Local vars
```

Obviously I don't want to be getting this error but rather just to have the app work... I tried switching my app over to postgresql for deployment but it was developed in sqlite. I have not taken any of the migrations or database files into production, I made sure to do a fresh migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is beacause version mismatch of django on your localhost and server.

Upgrade your `django version` on the server (digital ocean droplet) to match with the one you were developing in localhost.

By default they provide `django-1.6` in One-Click-Install. You need to upgrade then everything will work fine.

> pip install --upgrade django